# Download images from Category and metadata

Tags: image, metadata, wiki, wikipedia-api

I'm completely new to this so be gentle. I need to download all the images from a wiki commons image gallery e.g https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Air_Ministry_Second_World_War_Official_Collection

I need to download the original image and strip the wiki description for that image from the wiki page and add it to the image caption/title field in the images metadata..

please can someone help me and make me a very happy chappy

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can get the description via the `extmetadata` property of the [imageinfo API](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%20imageinfo). Other than that, you just need to choose (or write) some API client and do it. [wptools](https://github.com/siznax/wptools) is pretty simple to use, [pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) is probably the most powerful, with many ready-made scripts.